# Check that all combinations occur equally often for specified columns of a dataframe

Tags: r, combinatorics

You have a data frame. How best to check whether all combinations of the values of particular columns occur equally often?

(This is sometimes needed when dealing with the data file from an experiment with a factorial designs. Each column is an independent variable and we want to check that all combinations of the independent variables occurr equally often).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about `replications()`?

```
tmp <- transform(ToothGrowth, dose = factor(dose))

replications( ~ supp + dose, data = tmp)
replications( ~ supp * dose, data = tmp)

> replications( ~ supp + dose, data = tmp)
supp dose 
  30   20 
> replications( ~ supp * dose, data = tmp)
     supp      dose supp:dose 
       30        20        10
```

And from `?replications` we have a test for balance:

```
!is.list(replications(~ supp + dose, data = tmp))

> !is.list(replications(~ supp + dose, data = tmp))
[1] TRUE
```

The output from `replications()` isn't quite what you might expect, but the test shown using it gives the answer you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
checkAllCombosOccurEquallyOften<- function(df,colNames,dropZeros=FALSE) {
    #in data.frame df, check whether the factors in the list colNames reflect full factorial design (all combinations of levels occur equally often)
    #
    #dropZeros is useful if one of the factors nested in the others. E.g. testing different speeds for each level of    
    # something else, then a lot of the combos will occur 0 times because that speed not exist for that level.
    #but it's dangerous to dropZeros because it won't pick up on 0's that occur for the wrong reason- not fully crossed
    #
    #Returns:
    # true/false, and prints informational message
    #
    listOfCols <- as.list( df[colNames] )
    t<- table(listOfCols)

    if (dropZeros) {  
        t<- t[t!=0]   
    }           
    colNamesStr <- paste(colNames,collapse=",")
    if ( length(unique(t)) == 1 ) { #if fully crossed, all entries in table should be identical (all combinations occur equally often)
          print(paste(colNamesStr,"fully crossed- each combination occurred",unique(t)[1],'times'))
          ans <- TRUE
      } else {
          print(paste(colNamesStr,"NOT fully crossed,",length(unique(t)),'distinct repetition numbers.'  ))
          ans <- FALSE
      } 
    return(ans)
}
```

Load a dataset and call the above function

```
library(datasets)
checkAllCombosOccurEquallyOften(ToothGrowth,c("supp","dose")) #specify dataframe and columns
```

Output provides the answer, that it's fully crossed:

```
[1] "supp,dose fully crossed- each combination occurred 10 times"
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: I wouldn't call this "combinations", but rather "groups" or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Using the same `ToothGrowth` data:

```
library(datasets)
library(data.table)

dt = data.table(ToothGrowth)

setkey(dt, supp, dose)
dt[CJ(unique(supp), unique(dose)), .N] # note: using hidden by-without-by
#   supp dose  N
#1:   OJ  0.5 10
#2:   OJ  1.0 10
#3:   OJ  2.0 10
#4:   VC  0.5 10
#5:   VC  1.0 10
#6:   VC  2.0 10
```

You can then check if all `N`'s are equal or whatever else you like.